# Can I install CRM Email Router in two different servers?

Tags: dynamics-crm, email-router

In the company we have 3 instances of Dynamics CRM:

- A(production 2015),
- B(development 2015),
- C(development 2016).

Currently the Email Router is configured to manage "A" and "B", we want to test the new version of the email router 2016 and point it to instance "C", the router will be installed in a different server.

If I use the same configuration we have for "B" will the incoming emails be sent to "B" and "C" or this will cause conflicts between the two routers?

It's safe to have more then one email router when they are pointing to different CRM instances within the same organization?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This are just instruction on how to install them but doesn't answer my question